# Дано натуральное число n>10. Составить программу для вычисления значения

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int  main(void)
{
    float a, b, c, n;
    if (n > 10);
    int x = 1;
    printf("vvedite chiclo \n");
    scanf_s("%f",&b);
    b = (2 * cos(n - 1)) * (x) + cos (n*x);
    printf("%f", b);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно... В чем у вас проблема, поясните подробнее.

Comment: *циклы* *(8 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor Можно и без них, сумма записывается аналитически :)

Comment: Мне нужно указать,то что дано натуральное число n>10,и на основании числа,нужно вычислить значение.

Comment: Просто мне не понятно,как правильнее указать что есть число n>10

Comment: Кому указать? Выполнить проверку и при n <= 10 затребовать новый ввод?

Comment: Явно не сказано, как оно дано: вводится пользователем с клавиатуры, читается из файла, передается как аргумент в программу или берется откуда-то еще. Поэтому можно просто его указать к примеру как `int n = 23433` в начале программы.

Comment: Я насколько понял,нужно в программе вести заданное число с 1 до 9,ну чтобы число доходило до 10,и решить данное число в примере (2 * cos(заданное число) - 1)) * (x) + cos (заданное число)*x). Надеюсь обьяснил)

Comment: Запутали окончательно...

Comment: Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры число  n>10(число которое больше чем 10) ,позже программа должна данное число как бы встроить в пример,и в конечном итоге решить данный пример. (Я немного ошибся,когда сказал с 1 до 9 - неправильно написал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    start:
    cout << "Введите n больше чем 10: \n";
    int n;

    //Считываем значение n
    cin >> n;

    // Проверка введенного числа
    if (n <= 10) {
        cout << "Ваше n меньше чем 10 :(   \n";
        cout << "Повторите ввод\n";
        goto start;

    }
    // Если больше чем 10 продолжаем
    else {
        //TODO: ДАЛЬШЕ ПРОГРАММИРУЕТЕ СВОЮ ФОРМУЛУ И ВЫВОДИТЕ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
    } 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж `<=`, а не `<`.

Answer (score 3):

Вычисление ряда вот:

```
double Y(double x, unsigned int n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
        sum += (n-k+1)*cos(k*x);
    return sum;
}
```

А вот его применение (у вас же C++):

```
int main() {
    unsigned int n;
    double x;
    do {
        cout << "Введите n > 10: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n <= 10) cout << "Неверный ввод! ";
    } while(n <= 10);
    cout << "Введите x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "y = " << Y(x,n) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 0;
float b = 0, x = 0;
while (n < 10) {
    printf("vvedite chiclo > 10\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &n);
}
// тут каким то способом инициализируйте `x`
```

После ввода данных расчет лучше выполнить  так:

```
 for (int k = n; k > 0; --k) {
            b += k * cos(x);
            x += x;
    }
```

Тут меньше вычислительных операций, и  добавлять значение в каждом цикле намного быстрее, чем каждый раз умножать на какое то число.